# How to find count of repeatable elements in scala list

Tags: list, scala

Suppose you have a `List(1,1,1,4,4,1)` and have to calculate how many times is element that is a head of the list consecutively repeated. In the example above, method should return 3. In this method we only care about the first element.

I got this far and got stuck. Given a the first non repeatable character, i'd like to break, how how?

```
 def firstRepeated [X] (xs: List[X]) : Int = xs match {
     case Nil    => 0
     case y::ys  => ys match {
       case Nil   => 0
       case z::zs => if (y == z) 1 + firstRepeated(zs) else // break
     }
 }
```

Also, in the code above, i don't think i am properly handling a case when list is `z::Nil`

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Just a clarification. When you say consecutively repeated, you mean how many repetitions of the head are *right after* the head itself? Or in general how many times the head is repeated within the whole list? To make it clear, please answer the following: `firstRepeated(List(1,1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1)) = ?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also a method for this in [`GenSeqLike`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/GenSeqLike.html) (which `List` inherit from): `prefixLength`.
That makes a very short answer:

```
s.prefixLength(_==s.head)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm trying it on `val xs = List(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,1)` as `xs.prefixLength(_==xs.head)` and it gives me the answer as `5` when the right answer should be `6`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PlastyGrove: Isn't there a typo in your example list? I count 5 ones at the beginning of your list, not 6, so it should return 5...

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I thought the question was to count the number of times the head element repeats in the tail of the list. So prefixLength gives me the number of consecutive list items that satisfy the given predicate starting from the head of the list. Didn't understand it clearly until I did `xs.prefixLength(_<2)`. Interesting method, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

```
xs.headOption.map(h => xs.takeWhile(_ == h).size).getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: Very neat! Is there a way to correct my case logic above. Just trying to understand whether it can be done using it

Comment: @Jam: Please look at my answer, I've described a way to implement the case logic you've used

Comment: @Jam, tried doing it but don't feel too good about what I came up with. :(

Comment: `(h ==)` is a postfix op (it is not valid operator notation because the argument is missing) and it is also a Yoda condition...

Comment: @sschaef, hmm, okay. Rolled back the rollback. I haven't used it in my code since 2.10 came out so wasn't aware it was hidden behind the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
xs.span(_ == xs.head)._1.size
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
def getHeadCount(xs:List[Int]) = xs.count(_==xs.head)-1
val x = List(1,1,1,4,4,1)
getHeadCount(x) //Returns 3
```

But to answer your question, you really don't need to break. I've gone through your code and the fundamental problem is in the line

```
case z::zs => if (y == z) 1 + firstRepeated(zs) else // break
```

`zs` here is no longer your original array and running `firstRepeated` on that will do the count using the first element in `zs` which may or may not be the first element in `xs`. Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
def firstRepeated[X](xs: List[X]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => 0
  case y :: ys => ys match {
    case Nil => 0
    case z :: zs => {
      if (y == z) {
        //println(zs)
        1 + firstRepeated(z :: zs)
      } else {
        firstRepeated(y :: zs)
      }
    }
  }
}                                               //> firstRepeated: [X](xs: List[X])Int

val x = List(1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1)                  //> x  : List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1)

firstRepeated(x)                                //> res0: Int = 3
```

Take a look and let me know if you have any questions about the way it's implemented.