# How can I find repeated items in a Scala List?

Tags: scala

I have a Scala List that contains some repeated numbers. I want to count the number of times a specific number will repeat itself. For example:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,3,4,2,8,4,3,3,5)
val repeats = list.takeWhile(_ == List(3,3)).size
```

And the val `repeats` would equal `2`.

Obviously the above is pseudo-code and `takeWhile` will not find two repeated `3`s since `_` represents an integer. I tried mixing both `takeWhile` and `take(2)` but with little success. I also referred code from [How to find count of repeatable elements in scala list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534248/how-to-find-count-of-repeatable-elements-in-scala-list) but it appears the author is looking to achieve something different.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look up "run-length encoding" as what you want is similar. Also `sliding` method.

Comment: It's not clear. Result 2 could mean two repetitions for this number - there are 2 occurrences of repetition of number 3 --OR-- max number in one repetition (here is also 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work in this case:

```
val repeats = list.sliding(2).count(_.forall(_ == 3))
```

The sliding(2) method gives you an iterator of lists of elements and successors and then we just count where these two are equal to 3.

Question is if it creates the correct result to List(3, 3, 3)? Do you want that to be 2 or just 1 repeat.

Comment: To answer you question, it would be 1 repeat. Doesn't matter how long it repeats. Also, very succinct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
val repeats = list.sliding(2).toList.count(_==List(3,3))
```

and more generally the following code returns tuples of element and repeats value for all elements:

```
scala> list.distinct.map(x=>(x,list.sliding(2).toList.count(_.forall(_==x))))
res27: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (2,0), (3,2), (4,0), (8,0), (5,0))
```

which means that the element '3' repeats 2 times consecutively  at 2 places and all others 0 times.

and also if we want element repeats 3 times consecutively  we just need to modify the code as follows:

```
list.distinct.map(x=>(x,list.sliding(3).toList.count(_.forall(_==x))))
```

in SCALA REPL:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,3,3,4,2,8,4,3,3,3,5)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5)

scala> list.distinct.map(x=>(x,list.sliding(3).toList.count(_==List(x,x,x))))
res29: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (2,0), (3,2), (4,0), (8,0), (5,0))
```

Even sliding value can be varied by defining a function as:

```
def repeatsByTimes(list:List[Int],n:Int) =
list.distinct.map(x=>(x,list.sliding(n).toList.count(_.forall(_==x))))
```

Now in REPL:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,3,4,2,8,4,3,3,5)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3, 3, 5)

scala> repeatsByTimes(list,2)
res33: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (2,0), (3,2), (4,0), (8,0), (5,0))

scala> val list = List(1,2,3,3,3,4,2,8,4,3,3,3,2,4,3,3,3,5)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5)

scala> repeatsByTimes(list,3)
res34: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (2,0), (3,3), (4,0), (8,0), (5,0))

scala>
```

We can go still further like given a list of integers and given a maximum number 
 of consecutive repetitions that any of the element can occur in the list, we may need a list of 3-tuples representing (the element, number of repetitions of this element, at how many places this repetition occurred). this is more exhaustive information than the above. Can be achieved by writing a function like this:

```
 def repeats(list:List[Int],maxRep:Int) =
 { var v:List[(Int,Int,Int)] = List();
 for(i<- 1 to maxRep)
 v = v ++ list.distinct.map(x=> 
 (x,i,list.sliding(i).toList.count(_.forall(_==x))))
 v.sortBy(_._1) }
```

in SCALA REPL:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,3,3,4,2,8,4,3,3,3,2,4,3,3,3,5)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5)


scala> repeats(list,3)
res38: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((1,1,1), (1,2,0), (1,3,0), (2,1,3), 
 (2,2,0), (2,3,0), (3,1,9), (3,2,6), (3,3,3), (4,1,3), (4,2,0), (4,3,0), 
 (5,1,1), (5,2,0), (5,3,0), (8,1,1), (8,2,0), (8,3,0))

scala>
```

These results can be understood as follows:

```
   1 times the element '1' occurred at 1 places.
   2 times the element '1' occurred at 0 places.
   ............................................
   ............................................
   .............................................
   2 times the element '3' occurred at 6 places..
   .............................................
   3 times the element '3' occurred at 3 places...
   ............................................and so on.
```

Comment: Why add `toList`? It doesn't appear to serve any purpose. Also, this is almost the same as the answer that was accepted 4 years ago. When adding one more answer to an old question it is good to point out what your answer offers that is different from the others.

Comment: The old answer is ok..but this generalizes and repeats values for all elements in one go..a little improvement I feel at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  if (ls.isEmpty) List(List())
  else {
    val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
    if (next == Nil) List(packed)
    else packed :: pack(next)
  }
}

def encode[A](ls: List[A]): List[(Int, A)] = pack(ls) map { e => (e.length, e.head) }

val numberOfNs = list.distinct.map{ n =>
  (n -> list.count(_ == n))
 }.toMap

val runLengthPerN = runLengthEncode(list).map{ t => t._2 -> t._1}.toMap

val nRepeatedMostInSuccession = runLengthPerN.toList.sortWith(_._2 <= _._2).head._1
```

Where runLength is defined as below from [scala's 99 problems problem 9](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p09.scala) and [scala's 99 problems problem 10](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p10.scala).

Since `numberOfNs` and `runLengthPerN` are `Maps`, you can get the population count of any number in the list with `numberOfNs(number)` and the length of the longest repitition in succession with `runLengthPerN(number)`. To get the `runLength`, just compute as above with `runLength(list).map{ t => t._2 -> t._1 }`.

Comment: I dont think that is quite what he wants.

Comment: Yeah, I am unsure, as well. Maybe he wants to have a list of repetitions in a row? I will add that example, as well as one that finds the longest repetition.

Comment: Just figured it out and I am submitting an answer now :)

Comment: I think he want a function (List,int)=>int that will find the longest repetition of the int passed as an argument. In his example, for 3 wants to see 2 as result.

Comment: Thanks to [DeLongey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/737455/delongey) and of course, [Phil Gold](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Luigi Plinge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770361/luigi-plinge) I was able to use methods in run-length encoding to group together items in a list that repeat. I used some snippets from this page here: http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/

```
var n = 0
runLengthEncode(totalFrequencies).foreach{ o => 
  if(o._1 > 1 && o._2==subjectNumber) n+=1
}
n
```

The method `runLengthEncode` is as follows:

```
  private def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
    if (ls.isEmpty) List(List())
    else {
      val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
      if (next == Nil) List(packed)
      else packed :: pack(next)
    }
  }

  private def runLengthEncode[A](ls: List[A]): List[(Int, A)] =
    pack(ls) map { e => (e.length, e.head) }
```

I'm not entirely satisfied that I needed to use the mutable var `n` to count the number of occurrences but it did the trick. This will count the number of times a number repeats itself no matter how many times it is repeated.

Comment: You can avoid the var using the `count` method, or more generally `foldLeft`

Answer (score 0):

If you knew your list was not very long you could do it with **Strings**.

```
val list = List(1,2,3,3,4,2,8,4,3,3,5)
val matchList = List(3,3)
(matchList.mkString(",")).r.findAllMatchIn(list.mkString(",")).length
```

Answer (score 0):

From you pseudocode I got this working:

```
val pairs = list.sliding(2).toList  //create pairs of consecutive elements
val result = pairs.groupBy(x => x).map{ case(x,y) => (x,y.size);   //group pairs and retain the size, which is the number of occurrences.
```

`result` will be a `Map[List[Int], Int]` so you can the count number like:

```
 result(List(3,3))    // will return 2
```

I couldn't understand if you also want to check lists of several sizes, then you would need to  change the parameter to `sliding` to the desired size.